# Labelling arc in network flow diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, edge

I produced the following image with the Latex code below. Can anyone explain how to make the nodes and text bigger and label the arcs, for example add label 3 to the arc connecting n1 and n2?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sf]
\node[draw,circle,label=below:$n_1$] (n1) at (0,0){};
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$n_2$] (n2) at (2,2){}; 
\node[draw,circle,label=above:$n_3$] (n3) at (2,1){}; 
 \draw[thick,-latex] (n1) -- (n2);

 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am aiming to produce an image like this one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** At first version of bot examples I forgot on edge labels. Now added.

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
V/.style = {circle, draw, font=\sffamily, minimum size=2em, inner sep =2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small\sffamily, sloped}
                        ]
\node[V] (n1) {n1};
\node[V, above right=of n1] (n2)    {n2};
\node[V, at={(n1 -| n2)}]   (n3)    {n3};
\node[V, below right=of n1] (n4)    {n4};
\node[V, right=of n2]       (n5)    {t};
%
\path   (n1) edge ["3"] (n2)
        (n1) edge (n3)
        (n1) edge (n4)
        (n3) edge[red, "5"]      (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
For positioning you can use option `on grid`. In this case distances between nodes are measured between their centers, i.e. they lay on the grid with distances specified by `node distance`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 22mm, on grid,
V/.style = {circle, draw, font=\sffamily, minimum size=2em, inner sep =2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, shorten > = 1mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small\sffamily, sloped}
                        ]
\node[V] (n1) {n1};
\node[V, above right=of n1] (n2)    {n2};
\node[V, right=of n1]       (n3)    {n3};
\node[V, below right=of n1] (n4)    {n4};
\node[V, right=of n2]       (n5)    {t};
%
\path   (n1) edge ["3"]  (n2)
        (n1) edge        (n3)
        (n1) edge        (n4)
        (n3) edge[red, "5"]     (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is similar as before:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything else is fine but the line (n3) edge[red ["5"] ]
                                        (n5); causes an error: Package pgf Error: No shape named `' is known.. The edge is from n3 to n1 and not t. Can you tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: @user402525, ups, I make error at writing label of red arrows. It should be `(n3) edge[red, "5"]  (n5)`. Now is corrected in both examples.